# "Missing $ inserted" errors generated in tabular figure

Tags: tables, errors, compiling

I've compiled my LaTeX document into a PDF using the website ScribTeX, and everything seems to look fine, but I keep getting the following errors:

[image]

Similar errors happen every time I use a table.

The code in question is this block, which starts with line 141:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}

\hline
`a' \rightarrow  \tt{e}, \tt{@}, \tt{A} \\
`nice' \rightarrow   \tt{naIs}, \tt{nis} \\
`cold' \rightarrow \tt{kould} \\
`hour' \rightarrow \tt{aU\char18 r} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionfonts
\caption[queryDBwithOrthoWordForSampa example]{ In this and all subsequent diagrams, a `string in quotes' indicates an orthographic word or phrase, and a \texttt{monospaced string} indicates that it is a SAMPA word or phrase.  }
\label{fig:oronymGeneration:queryDBwithOrthoWordForSampa}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Read [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT) Not only is your use of `\tt` as an argument-taking macro incorrect, (it's actually an old-school switch), it's considered obsolete.

Answer (score 16):

As the error says, you're missing `$` signs. This is because  `\rightarrow` is a math mode command, and must be used in math mode.

You can solve the problem by using `$\rightarrow$` instead.