# “Missing $ inserted” errors generated in tabular figure

Tags: tables, math-mode, article

I've used the code below which doesn't seem to be working for my Latex table. I think it might be because I'm using the iopart document class. It gives me the following error.

```
<inserted text> 
                $
l.456 ...ngth L ($\mu$ m) & Density of PDMS (Kg/m^
                                                  3) \nonumber\\
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.457 \mr
```

```
\begin{table}
\caption{\label{TableOfValues}Dimensions of example to be solved}
\begin{indented}
\item[]\begin{tabular}{p{0.15in}p{0.3in}p{0.3in}p{0.6in}p{0.2in}p{0.25in}p{0.3in}}
\br
Sr. no & Breadth b ($\mu$ m) & Height h ($\mu$ m) & Young's Modulus E of PDMS (GPa) & Gap g ($\mu$ m) & Length L ($\mu$ m) & Density of PDMS (Kg/m^3) \nonumber\\
\mr
1&300&10&0.750&5&800&970\\
2&300&8&0.750&5&800&970\\
3&300&9&0.750&5&800&970\\
4&300&11&0.750&5&800&970\\
5&300&12&0.750&5&800&970\\
6&300&10&0.750&5&600&970\\
7&300&10&0.750&5&700&970\\
8&300&10&0.750&5&900&970\\
9&300&10&0.750&5&1000&970\\
10&300&10&0.750&3&800&970\\
11&300&10&0.750&4&800&970\\
12&300&10&0.750&6&800&970\\
13&300&10&0.750&7&800&970\\
\br
\end{tabular}
\end{indented}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you write `m^3`. Put `m$^3$` or write `m\textasciicircum 3`. It depends on what you want.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175335/tables-missing-inserted?rq=1

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86192/missing-inserted-errors-generated-in-tabular-figure?rq=1

Comment: In this case, the error message is quite informative.  You tried to use math-mode syntax outside of math mode.

Answer (score 3):

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete document, which can be compile as it is and which demonstrate your problem.
- Since the preamble of your document is unknown, some commands in your table is not defined.
- For units of variable is very sensible to use the `siunitx` package. Using it, your problem is avoided.
- column headers are very long, so the table probably spill out of right text border. A solution is break column headers by use `makcell` command (defined in the package of the same name) into two lines and use shortens for very long text with explanation at bottom of table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx} % package for dummy text

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\caption{Dimensions of example to be solved}
\label{TableOfValues}
\begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=2.0]
                S[table-format=3.0]
                S[table-format=2.0]
                S[table-format=1.3]
                S[table-format=1.0]
                S[table-format=4.0]
                S[table-format=3.0]
                @{}}
    \toprule
{\makecell{Sr.\\ no}} 
    & {\makecell{Breadth\\ b (\si{\micro\metre})}} 
            & {\makecell{Height\\ h (\si{\micro\metre})}}
                & {\makecell{Modulus*\\ E (GPa)}}
                        & {\makecell{Gap\\g (\si{\micro\metre})}}
                            & {\makecell{Length\\ L (\si{\micro\metre})}} 
                                    & {\makecell{Density of\\ PDMS (\si{\kilogram\per\cubic\metre})}} \\
    \midrule
1   &300    &10 &0.750  &5  &800    &970    \\
2   &300    &8  &0.750  &5  &800    &970    \\
3   &300    &9  &0.750  &5  &800    &970    \\
4   &300    &11 &0.750  &5  &800    &970    \\
5   &300    &12 &0.750  &5  &800    &970    \\
6   &300    &10 &0.750  &5  &600    &970    \\
7   &300    &10 &0.750  &5  &700    &970    \\
8   &300    &10 &0.750  &5  &900    &970    \\
9   &300    &10 &0.750  &5  &1000   &970    \\
10  &300    &10 &0.750  &3  &800    &970    \\
11  &300    &10 &0.750  &4  &800    &970    \\
12  &300    &10 &0.750  &6  &800    &970    \\
13  &300    &10 &0.750  &7  &800    &970    \\
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\small
*: Young's Modulus E of PDMS (GPa)}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions and comments:

- Load the `siunitx` package and use its `\si` macro to typeset scientific units. E.g., `\si{\micro\meter}` and `\si{\kilo\gram\per\meter\cubed}`.
- Still using the capabilities of the `siunitx` package, use its `S` column type to align the numbers in all 7 columns on their (explicit or implicit) decimal markers.
- Employ a `tabularx` environment and use its `X` column type to typeset the header cells while allowing automatic line breaking. In the example below, I utilize a variable-width and centered version of the `X` column types. Note that the sum of the variable widths is `7`, i.e., the number of columns of type `X`. (Aside: The relative widths were obtained in part by trial-and-error; the objective was to make the content of all header cells to fit in just two lines.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash%
    \hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Dimensions of example to be solved} \label{TableOfValues}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
  T{2.0}T{3.0}T{2.0}T{1.3}T{1.0}T{4.0}T{3.0} 
  @{}}
\toprule
  \mc{@{}C{0.3}}{Sr.\ no}
& \mc{C{0.75}}{Breadth $b$ (\si{\micro\meter})} 
& \mc{C{0.75}}{Height $h$ (\si{\micro\meter})} 
& \mc{C{2.1}}{Young's Modulus $E$ of PDMS (\si{\giga\pascal})} 
& \mc{C{0.65}}{Gap $g$~(\si{\micro\meter})}
& \mc{C{0.75}}{Length $L$ (\si{\micro\meter})}
& \mc{C{1.7}@{}}{Density of PDMS (\si{\kilo\gram\per\meter\cubed})} \\
\midrule
 1 & 300 & 10 & 0.750 & 5 & 800 & 970\\
 2 & 300 &  8 & 0.750 & 5 & 800 & 970\\
 3 & 300 &  9 & 0.750 & 5 & 800 & 970\\
 4 & 300 & 11 & 0.750 & 5 & 800 & 970\\
 5 & 300 & 12 & 0.750 & 5 & 800 & 970\\
 6 & 300 & 10 & 0.750 & 5 & 600 & 970\\
 7 & 300 & 10 & 0.750 & 5 & 700 & 970\\
 8 & 300 & 10 & 0.750 & 5 & 900 & 970\\
 9 & 300 & 10 & 0.750 & 5 &1000 & 970\\
10 & 300 & 10 & 0.750 & 3 & 800 & 970\\
11 & 300 & 10 & 0.750 & 4 & 800 & 970\\
12 & 300 & 10 & 0.750 & 6 & 800 & 970\\
13 & 300 & 10 & 0.750 & 7 & 800 & 970\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```